# Hibernate, could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

В учебных целях хочу написать приложение на `Spring + Hibernate` с возможностью авторизации и отправки сообщений. Создал сущности, сервис и контроллер но когда захожу на стартовую страницу на которой производится выборка списка зарегистрированных пользователей, вылазит ошибка `could not extract ResultSet`. Значю что где то есть косяк, но из за недостатка опыта найти его не получается, Google тоже не помог.

> [Ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/Bleser92/blog-1.3)
>   [Лог ошибки](https://github.com/Bleser92/blog-1.3/blob/master/localhost.2016-10-16.log)

Comment: Hibernate говорит: `ERROR: column messages0_.user_id does not exist`, видимо в БД у таблицы `messages` нет поля `user_id`

Comment: В это таблице есть поле id_user.

Comment: В качестве отступления: за такой код - `session.createQuery("from net.bleser.entity.User as user where user.username='"+username+"'", User.class)` - линейкой по рукам.

Comment: Где Ваша внимательность? `user_id`  и `id_user` это же ведь разные поля! Сделал pull request для авто-генерации таблиц, можете принять запрос. Вас за этот проект прибить мало, дублирование бинов в xml и аннотациями, у сущностей нет конструктора по умолчанию, и гет/сет у одной. Это что сразу в глаза бросилось. Тут много еще чего всплывет.

Comment: У меня еще мало опыта в использовании `Spring` и `Hibernate`, я понимаю что мой код убог.
Но все же почему используется имя для поля `user_id` ведь я прописал в аннотации какие поля связывать `@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_role")`

Comment: На гитхабе не увидел, что прописано такое поле у сущности `Message`,  гибернейт правильно возмущается.

Comment: У Вас сначала загружается сущность `User`, далее загружается список `List<Message>`, т.к. стоит параметр `FetchType.EAGER`, а в БД у сущности `Message` хибернейт не видит поля `user_id`. То, что Вы указали на `@JoinTable`, то это не относится к возникаемой ошибке, т.к. прогружается сущность `Message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало когда в сущности `Message` сделал так:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
private User user;
```